# SVG not displaying in Media Tab in Backend

Tags: uploads, media, thumbnails, svg

I addes this code to allow SVG Uploads to the Media Library of wordpress:

```
function upload_svg ( $svg_mime ){
$svg_mime['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
return $svg_mime;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'upload_svg' );
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

Than I added some SVGs to the Media Library. Using them works perfectly fine. The only Issue I have is that they will not be displayed in the Media Library. On other Pages in the Backend they display fine.

Is there anything I can do to display them in the Media Tab aswell? I couln't find anything online on how to fix this issue.

Comment: The solution is lengthy. Here's an external link: https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-svg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to allow SVG upload and preview to Media area of WordPress: https://gist.github.com/benfrain/9422862

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/.
I use it and .svg files seems fine in media lib.